# w2ui grid: Unable to get focus in editable divs

Tags: w2ui

I want to be able to expand a row and show an editable div and be able to edit it. However when i put my text cursor in the editable div it almost immediately loses focus.
Is there any way to stop the div from losing focus?

I have made a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/h2zoqm0n/1/

The sample code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({ 
        name: 'grid', 
        header: 'List of Names',
        records: [
        { "recid": 1, "fname": "John", "lname": "Doe", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 2, "fname": "Stuart", "lname": "Motzart", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 3, "fname": "Jin", "lname": "Franson", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 4, "fname": "Susan", "lname": "Ottie", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 5, "fname": "Kelly", "lname": "Silver", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 6, "fname": "Francis", "lname": "Gatos", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 7, "fname": "Mark", "lname": "Welldo", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 8, "fname": "Thomas", "lname": "Bahh", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" },
        { "recid": 9, "fname": "Sergei", "lname": "Rachmaninov", "email": "jdoe@gmail.com", "sdate": "4/3/2012" }

        ],
        method: 'GET', // need this to avoid 412 error on Safari
        show: {
            header         : true,
            toolbar     : true,
            footer        : true,
            lineNumbers    : true,
            selectColumn: true,
            expandColumn: true
        },        
        columns: [                
            { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%' },
            { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%' },
            { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '40%' },
            { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', size: '120px' }
        ],
        searches: [
            { type: 'int',  field: 'recid', caption: 'ID' },
            { type: 'text', field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name' },
            { type: 'text', field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name' },
            { type: 'date', field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date' }
        ],
        onExpand: function (event) {
            var data = w2ui.grid.get(event.recid);
            var cmp1 = data.fname;
            var cmp2 = data.lname;
            $('#' + event.box_id).html('<div style=""><table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td>' + cmp1 + '</td><td><div id="d" style="white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid black;" contenteditable="true">' + cmp2 + '</div></td></tr></table ></div>');
        }
    });    
});
```

... and there is a div with the id "grid":

```
<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **input** element with ***autofocus attribute*** inside div for edit cmp2 value

an example for your  onExpand function

```
onExpand: function (event) {
            var data = w2ui.grid.get(event.recid);
                    var cmp1 = data.fname;
                    var cmp2 = data.lname.replace("\n", "<br>");
                    $('#' + event.box_id).html('<div style=""><table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td>' + cmp1 + '</td><td><div id="DataInExcelEdit" style="white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid black;" contenteditable="true"> <input style="width:100%" autofocus value=' + cmp2 + ' /></div></td></tr></table ></div>');
        }
```

**and more**
I think you should edit in cell not when column expanded, this is not effective way [look at that](http://jsfiddle.net/ty77umx1/1/)

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that? If they wanted a form field, then they could just use a form field. They wouldn't need a contenteditable div.